# Response.body is Empty Flutter

Tags: android, json, api, flutter, dart

I am trying to retrieve Data from https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/ with the following request and I am getting an Empty body
Any Ideas how to retrieve data from this type of API. Thanks
full code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<String> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/",
    );
    var data = response.body;
    print(data);
    return response.body;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          getData();
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Hello World"),
      ),
    
    );
  }    
}
```

**Problem Solved !!!**
After I did a flutter upgrade everything just work properly, I still don't know how that happened

**Flutter doctor before Upgrade**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):                                                                  
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-10.0.pre.111, on Microsoft Windows 
[Version 10.0.18363.1082], locale en-US)                                                                                                                                 
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)                                            ! Some Android licenses not 
accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses                      
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)

[√] VS Code (version 1.50.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

**Flutter doctor afterUpgrade**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.23.0-8.0.pre.284, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.50.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: This API doesn't seem to be CORS-compatible; you're expected to call it from server, not from client.

Comment: Does that mean I can't work with it on flutter ? sorry I am still new to this API thing, thanks

Comment: @raina77ow can you give me an example of how I can do it or something that can help Understand, thank you.

Comment: It means the in web world you're expected to call that API from backend, then (with your app) consume that backend. [Here's the issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46904) with a lengthy discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this ?

```
  Future<String> getData() async {
   http.Response response = await http.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/");
var data = response.body;
   print(data );
   return response.body;
  }
```

Thing above works for sure. I tested it and attaching the screenshot.
[image]

If you want to get the return value by another variable for example like this:

```
String data = getData();
```

It won't work you need to listen to the future like this:

```
String data = getData().then((value) => value);
```

`P.S:` This answer does not deserve -1.

Comment: I am getting the following error because the body is empty i can't call json.decode()

E/flutter ( 9090): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 9090):
E/flutter ( 9090): ^
E/flutter ( 9090):
E/flutter ( 9090): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5))
E/flutter ( 9090): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:522:7))

Comment: import dart:convert

Comment: or you can remove json.decode and do following 

response.body.toString()

I think json data we are getting from website is not properly formatted or not in the way that json.decode will understand.

so just transform the body to string  and print it to view the result

Comment: also you can to not use toString I believe it will print the data with just print(response.body)

Comment: Imported dart:convert as convert and used **convert.jsonDecode(response.body)** and I am getting the same error.

Comment: also api is not blocked as someone mentioned in your comment as long as you can access it from pure browser it means that you will be able to access it from anywhere if it does not have any user-agent control from it's side, cause you are making just plain GET requests in both cases. in this case you can send fake chrome user agent as a headers while making http.get request

Comment: **Print(response.body.toString())** returns " " still because the response.body I am getting from **http.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/");** is Empty, the problem is not in the format the problem is I am getting an empty **response.body**. Thanks

Comment: Okay, then, I can get the data with postman software, I am gonna test in dart now will need 5 minutes

Comment: I am sorry, but I literally Copied and Pasted your code and run it and I am still getting an empty body, I really can't understand where is the problem.

Comment: paste your full code here I am playing guessing game without the complete code here.

Comment: Funny thing is I copy pasted all of your code and it is working here.
whatever it is it is not code, it is some background issue.
But try restarting your emulator and android studio and try again.

Comment: I believe the problem is because I have flutter web enabled or because I am working on flutter channel master I am gonna disable flutter web or go back to stable and see what happens.

Comment: I am on flutter master too.

Comment: Disabled flutter web and tried on emulator and on real device and still nothing !!!

Comment: maybe adding the network permissions in android manifest

Comment: view this:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/networking

Comment: network permission was added since I created the project...

Comment: open the directory of your project in cmd and run flutter clean, than try again

Comment: I've already run flutter clean and flutter pub get ...

Comment: Hey, so the problem happened again and I can't get the data, body is empty can you please retry the code and tell me if it's working, Thank you so much.